# Is it possible to redefine the equal operator for tuples?

Tags: python

I have some code in which edges are represented as tuple

```
(vertex_1, vertex_2)
```

and I have lists of edges that represent planar embedded faces, as for the example below.

I need to search if an edge is present in the list, but I need to return true both if a use `(v1, v2)` and `(v2, v1)`:

```
f1 = [(6, 1), (1, 2), (2, 7), (7, 6)]
(6,1) in f1
(1,6) in f1

True
False
```

Comment: You can use a `set` or `frozenset`(hashable).

Comment: I'm reeeeally new to python!

Comment: Yes: subclass or make your own simple class. No: the default `__eq__` and `__contains__` function cannot be changed for existing tuple objects, it's a builtin function bound to the class object

Comment: A `set`/`frozenset` is _not_ the same thing as an unordered `list`/`tuple`. The duplicate elements will get lost in translation, such as `(6, 6)`.

Comment: Ok thanks! :-( The lists of tuple are returned that way directly by the Sage libraries I'm using (the faces() funtion for the graph theory libraries)

Comment: Another approach would be to force the tuples into a canonical order, e.g. require the lower number to be first.  Then if you're given `(7, 3)`, change it to `(3, 7)` to make it easier to find.

Comment: `(1, 6) in f1 or (6, 1) in f1` is too hard?

Comment: @Bakuriu: it is not to hard. The problem is that a have to use many time the search, in different branches of my program. I think (after having seen all the possibilities) I'll use a user defined funtion to do the check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot override the equality method for existing types, so you would have to create your own type which would then require you to replace all your existing tuples with your custom type.

If your main problem is just the `(6,1) in f1` use case, then maybe you should just consider creating a method for that instead:

```
def contains(t, lst):
    return (t[0], t[1]) in lst or (t[1], t[0]) in lst
```

And then you can just use it like this:

```
>>> f1 = [(6, 1), (1, 2), (2, 7), (7, 6)]
>>> contains((6, 1), f1)
True
>>> contains((1, 6), f1)
True
```

This essentially has the benefit that you don’t need to replace your tuples by a different type instead. So you can work with all your data sources the way they are.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a tuple subclass and change it's equality method (`__eq__`):

```
class UnorderedTuple(tuple):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return len(self) == len(other) and set(self) == set(other)
```

will work for your case with (tuple lengths == 2 if the tuple elements are hashable - that is immutable and have a well defined comparison)

To have your list of tuples converted to a list of Unordered tuples do:

```
f1 =  [UnorderedTuple(f_) for f_ in f1]
```

To have a proper containment query (the `in` operator) over a list can be slow - so you'd better have a set than a list:

```
set_f1 =  { UnorderedTuple(f_) for f_ in f1 }
(6,1) in set_f1
(1,6) in set_f1
```

This implementation will not be very performant, as it creates a new `set` for each comparison. So if your tuples will always be f two elements, it is more performant to have the `__eq__` method unroled like:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return super(UnordoredTuple, self).__eq__(other) or (self[0] == other[1] and self[1] == other[0])
```

Comment: It’s not a good idea to inherit from tuple here. A completely separate type should be used so this new type is not accidentally used for non-two-element items.

Comment: That depends on the needs of the O.P.  - if it is larger system qere these types will be used over and over again yes. If itis a smalll filtering script that will be worked on always the same datasets, there is no problem going  with this simpler solution.

Comment: "...Although practicality beats purity." - note that even Python builtin sequence types abide by this - leaving specialized container implementations to whoever cares for them - like btress, matrixes, and so on. You implement what you need.

Comment: No, this implementation does *not* work for tuple lengths longer than 2.  For instance, it would falsely report that `(2, 2, 3)` and `(2, 3, 3)` were equal.  It's safe for two-element tuples, but not more than that.

Comment: @poke and moreover - the idea of stackoverflow is to propose code suggestions to resolve the question presented, not full fledgeded production ready pieces of code that can withhold all possible corner cases.  The OP is a coder - if he needs a specilized object for a larger system, he can design that, and search for/ask for/ further doubts in other questions.

Comment: @jsbueno And the idea of Stack Overflow is also to point out possible problems so people won’t copy code without being aware of them. That’s what I did.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is it possible to redefine the equal operator for tuples"

Sort of.  You can't do it on the basic `tuple` type, but you can to it on a subclass:

```
 class MyTuple(tuple):
     def __eq__(self, other):
         orig_eq = super(MyTuple, self).__eq__(other)
         if orig_eq and orig_eq is not NotImplemented:
             return True
         else:
             return super(MyTuple, self).__eq__(other[::-1])
```

Generally, this probably isn't the best approach.  Depending on the constraints of the problem, you could try a set of frozenset:

```
f1_set = {frozenset(tup) for tup in f1}
frozenset((1, 6)) in f1_set
```

The advantage here is that if you're doing multiple membership tests on the same data, you'll likely get better runtime (Each membership test on the list is `O(N)` and you need to do up to two for each item you want to check whereas you only have a single `O(N)` step to build `f1_set` and then each membership test is `O(1)` afterward).

Answer (score 0):

like others have posted you can use class to redefine the equal operator for tuples, but still you have to use that class you have to call it, so if you have

```
class new_tuple:
    ...
```

than you have to use:

```
tuple = (1,6)
tuple = new_tuple(tuple)
```

i think it's easier to use function to determine if tuple is in list:

```
def check(tuple_, list_):
    v1, v2 = tuple_
    if (v1, v2) in list_ or (v2, v1) in list_:
        return True
    return False

f1 = [(6, 1), (1, 2), (2, 7), (7, 6)]
print(check((6, 1), f1))   # this prints True
print(check((1, 6), f1))   # this prints True
```

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this problem is to use [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), which are sets where an element may appear more than once.  The `collections` module defines a `Counter` class, which is a subclass of `dict`, that implements multisets.  The `dict` keys are the elements of the multiset, and the values are the number of times the keys occur.

This avoids limitations on the number of elements in the multiset, and is already available.  The main shortcoming is that there is no "frozen", hashable version that I know of.

Examples:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> Counter((3, 6, 2, 4, 2, 8)) == Counter((8, 4, 3, 6, 2, 2))
True

>>> Counter((3, 6, 2, 4, 2, 8)) == Counter((8, 4, 3, 6, 4, 2))
False
```

You can use the `Counter` class directly, which is probably simplest, but if you want to retain the underlying `tuple` representation, you can use the `Counter` class to implement a more general version of the `tuple` subclass that others have proposed:

```
class MultisetTuple(tuple):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return Counter(self) == Counter(other)
```

Examples:

```
>>> MultisetTuple((3, 6, 2, 4, 2, 8)) == MultisetTuple((8, 4, 3, 6, 2, 2))
True

>>> MultisetTuple((3, 6, 2, 4, 2, 8)) == MultisetTuple((8, 4, 3, 6, 4, 2))
False
```